# WebSocket Video Streaming Issue: Streamer Video Not Displaying on Viewer End

Tags: python, django, webrtc

I'm currently working on a Django project that involves live video streaming using WebRTC and Django Channels. I've set up a WebSocket connection between the streamer and the viewer for exchanging offer and answer data, and the WebSocket connection seems to be working fine. However, I'm facing an issue where the streamer's video is not being displayed on the viewer's end.

Here's a simplified overview of my setup:

I have a Django application with Django Channels enabled.
I'm using WebRTC for video streaming, and I've established a WebSocket connection between the streamer and the viewer.
The viewer sends an offer to the streamer using the WebSocket connection, and the streamer responds with an answer.
The viewer receives the answer through the WebSocket and sets up the peer connection to display the streamer's video.
However, despite the WebSocket connection working correctly and the offer and answer being exchanged, the streamer's video is not being displayed on the viewer's end. I've verified the SDP data exchange and ensured that the MediaStream is assigned to the video element.

stream.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Streamer Page</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Streamer Page</h1>
    <video id="localVideo" autoplay muted></video>
    <button id="startStreamButton">Start Streaming</button>
    <div id="stream-container" data-offer-url="{{ stream_url }}"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      const localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');
      const startStreamButton = document.getElementById("startStreamButton");
      const configuration = { iceServers: [{ urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }] };
      const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
      const container = document.getElementById("stream-container");
      const streamUrl = container.getAttribute("data-offer-url");

      startStreamButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
          .then(stream => {
            localVideo.srcObject = stream;

            // Add tracks to the peerConnection
            stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
              peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream);
            });

            peerConnection.createOffer()
              .then(offer => {
                peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
                const sdpData = offer.sdp;

                fetch('/streaming/create_offer/', {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                  },
                  body: new URLSearchParams({
                    stream_url: streamUrl,  
                    sdp: sdpData
                  })
                });
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error creating offer:', error);
              });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error accessing user media:', error);
          });
      });
    });

  </script>

</html>
```

viewer.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Viewer Experience</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="viewer-container">
      <h1>Viewer Experience</h1>
      <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay controls></video>
      <p>Stream URL: {{ stream_url }}</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
      <div id="stream-container" data-offer-url="{% url 'get_offer' %}?stream_url={{ stream_url }}"></div>
      <div id="send-stream-container" data-answer-url="{% url 'send-answer' %}?stream_url={{ stream_url }}"></div>
      <button id="copyButton">Copy Link</button>
    </div>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        const videoElement = document.getElementById("remoteVideo");
        const copyButton = document.getElementById("copyButton");
        const streamUrl = document.querySelector('p').textContent.split(": ")[1];

        const csrfToken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;

        const configuration = { iceServers: [{ urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }] };
        const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

        peerConnection.ontrack = (event) => {
          if (videoElement.srcObject !== event.streams[0]) {
            videoElement.srcObject = event.streams[0];
          }
        };
        // Establish WebSocket connection
        const socket = new WebSocket(`ws://${window.location.host}/ws/stream/${streamUrl}/`);

        socket.onopen = (event) => {
          console.log("WebSocket connection opened.");
        };

        socket.onmessage = (event) => {
          const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
          console.log("Received WebSocket message:", data);

          // Handle received message, update UI, etc.
        };

        socket.onclose = (event) => {
          console.log("WebSocket connection closed:", event);
        };

        fetch(`/streaming/get_offer/?stream_url=${streamUrl}`)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            const offerInit = {
              type: "offer",
              sdp: data.offer
            };
            const offer = new RTCSessionDescription(offerInit);
            return peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);
          })
          .then(() => peerConnection.createAnswer())
          .then(answer => {
            peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
            const answerData = { answer: answer.sdp };

            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('stream_url', streamUrl);
            formData.append('answer', answerData.answer);

            return fetch('/streaming/send-answer/', {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
              },
              body: formData
            });
          })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            console.log("Send Answer Response:", data);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error:", error);
          });

        copyButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
          const tempTextArea = document.createElement("textarea");
          tempTextArea.value = streamUrl;
          document.body.appendChild(tempTextArea);
          tempTextArea.select();
          document.execCommand("copy");
          document.body.removeChild(tempTextArea);
          alert("Stream URL copied to clipboard!");
        });

        peerConnection.onerror = (event) => {
          console.error("Error:", event);
        };

        peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = (event) => {
          if (peerConnection.iceConnectionState === "disconnected") {
            console.log("Disconnected from the stream.");
            // Handle UI changes here if needed.
          }
        };

        // ... Rest of the code
      });

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

consumers.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
import json
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

class StreamConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        # Get the stream URL from the URL parameters
        self.stream_url = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['stream_url']
        self.room_group_name = f'stream_{self.stream_url}'

        # Join the room group
        self.accept()

        # Add the consumer to the group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Remove the consumer from the group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    def receive(self, text_data):
        # Receive data from the WebSocket
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send data to the group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'stream_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    def stream_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))`

routing.py
`from django.urls import re_path

from .consumers import StreamConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/stream/(?P<stream_url>\w+)/$', StreamConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

complete code can be found  [Here](https://github.com/Codewithshagbaor/Video-Streaming/)
Please and if possible to run multiple connections

I have a Django application with Django Channels enabled.
I'm using WebRTC for video streaming, and I've established a WebSocket connection between the streamer and the viewer.